# Apache solr - more like this score

Tags: apache, solr

I have a small index with ~1000 documents with only two fields:
- id (string)
- content (text_general)

I noticed that when I do MLT search by id for similar content, the original document(which id is the searched id) have a score 5.241327.
There is 1:1 duplicated document and for the duplicated content it is returning score = 1.5258181. Why? Why it is not 5.241327 when it is 100% duplicate.

Another question is can I in any way to get similarity documents by content by passing some text in the query.
Example:

```
/mlt/?q=content:Some encoded long text&mlt.fl=content
```

I am trying to check if there is similar content uploaded and the check must be performed at new content upload time.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth to try some different parameters. I also use MLT on only one field, I use the following parameters:

'mlt.boost': 'true',
'mlt.fl': 'my_field_name',
'mlt.maxqt': 1000,
'mlt.mindf': '0',
'mlt.mintf': '0',
'qt': 'mlt',
'rows': '10'

See http://wiki.apache.org/solr/MoreLikeThis for an explanation of the parameters. I think with a small index mindf might be important and I see the default mintf (term frequency) is 2, so I assume an ID is only one term, so this is probably ignored!

Comment: Querying this:
http://192.168.2.100:8983/solr/site/select?q=content:%3Ch2%3EAlternative%20energy%3C/h2%3E&mlt=true&mlt.fl=content&mlt.mindf=0&mlt.mintf=0&fl=id,score&mlt.boost=true&mlt.maxqt=999999&mlt.count=1
Results in: [link](http://pastebin.com/7FyuXP6p)

Comment: So how may I know that the searching content is similar it will return match even if score is 0.001. I'm targeting to find content which are same in at least 50% or more.

Comment: When I look at the moreLikeThis result (not the first element 'response', but the second one) I see two high scores (3.564 and 3.559) with IDs 281 and 111 an one very low (0.018) with ID 131. Is this not what you expected?

Comment: I am confused. Can you tell me if you know how to make solr return the document which is similar at least 50% with the content I am passing to the query (which usually will be long text - at least 1000 chars). Or it will fit too if solr return only true OR false ('yes, there is similar document' OR 'no, there is no similar doc').

Comment: I want to note that I find that solr currently was running boolean query because the text was converted to If+you+have+some+tool... in other words spaces are replaced with + and in the log I was having exception telling that the maximum conditions (1024) was overheaded. Maybe this is the reason to not return correct results :S

Comment: And one more not: I am using solr-php-client - [link](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/)

Answer (score 0):

First, how does Solr More-Like-This works?

1. A regular Solr query is conducted (e.g. "?q=content:Some encoded long text&.....".
2. For each document returned by the above query, More-Like-This conduct More like this query...
   So, the first result set "response", is just like any Solr query results set.
   The More-Like-This appears below and start with something like that (Json format):
   "moreLikeThis":{
   "57375":{"numFound":18155,"start":0,"docs":["

For an explanation about More Like This algorithm, please read that: 
http://blog.brattland.no/node/18 
and: http://cephas.net/blog/2008/03/30/how-morelikethis-works-in-lucene/

If you didn't solved the problem yet, please let me know and I will guide you through.